# Mistakenly performed continuity test when power is on

Tags: multimeter

I forgot to turn off the power of system before I did some continuity test using a multimeter.

Basically an +-V dual supply was powering a transducer. Transducer was outputting very small offset like 100mV and had almost 8k output impedance so I'm not worried about that much.

But I also did continuity test between V+ and V-; V+ and GND; V- and GND ect.

When I each time heard continuity sound I noticed that I forgot to turn off the power. So I turned off and did the same test.

But many hours later I was afraid if I did damage the power supply.

[image]

What happens if nodes +15V and -15V or + for instance is checked with continuity of a multimeter when the power is on? I know that would be short if it were a wire but is there possibility power supply is not damaged?

Comment: I'd expect that the meter, rather than the power supplies, would be damaged, if any damage ocurred.

Comment: Your power supply is probably fine. Your meter might not be, though; make sure it still works.

Comment: Can anyone explain how the power supply is protected? I thought continuity test is just a diode:/

Comment: Power supplies are often (and lab power supplies almost always) designed to withstand some pretty bad conditions. What a multimeter does to check continuity is the same thing it does to measure resistance, apply a voltage and measure the current, and if the current is sufficiently high it will beep/light up the screen/whatever else it does to signal a positive continuity test.